# gcc compiler error when building on raspbian

Tags: c++, gcc, build, compiler-errors, raspbian

I am trying to build [openvibe](http://openvibe.inria.fr/pub/src/openvibe-2.0.0-src.tar.xz)!  source code on raspbian and i have installed all the required dependencies, one by one manually, but in the end it seems to have a compilation error.

So after writing build files it says:

```
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/Desktop/openvibe-2.0.0-src/build/sdk-Release
Generation succeeded!
Building project...
```

and:

```
[1/340] Building CXX object build-tool...
[some dirty code here]
```

and then stops building sdk

returning this :

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ERROR: Build failed
Error while building sdk
```

I want to make it clear that i have searched everywhere and SOF is my last resort! So any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `-msse2`is an x86-specific optimization flag for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You need to remove it, because it has no sense on ARM.

Comment: from the entire source code you mean?

Comment: BTW, I recommend asking, with a lot more details (explain every command you have typed) on some [OpenVIBE forum](http://openvibe.inria.fr/forum/). You might need to change some build configuration thing (e.g. for the [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool used by OpenVIBE; I don't know what it is; in general [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/) is used with a generator like [meson](http://mesonbuild.com/))

Comment: well i have posted there but that forum is not responsive at all regarding my urgent timeframe!

Comment: Then you need to dive yourself in the source code of `OpenVibe`  and understand their build infrastructure. You might need a few days for that. Once you have find out how to do that, be sure to publish that information, at least on their forum. Take advantage of the fact that OpenVibe is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You won't need to remove `-msse2` from the C++ source code, but you'll need to patch their build procedures

Comment: ninja was a dependency needed for the build.sh bash command. what i did was, because the install_dependecies.sh didnt run i ran build.sh and everytime it ran into dependency errors i manually installed the required dependency! and now no dependency errors are there but still this it not working.

Comment: Yes, you need to spend a few days understanding how that OpenVibe software is built. Ask yourself how is their `build.ninja` file generated. Perhaps `-msse2` is inside that file.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this "but you'll need to patch their build procedures" assuming im not that pro on the matter! :)) you mean i should modify the build process in general or modify build.sh command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the output, you are building the library using `cmake`.

`-msse2` is gcc compilation flag, which enables *x86* sse vectorisation. Since you are compiling for *raspbian* you need to disable it.

Usually, compilation flags are set in `CMakeLists.txt` files. Find, the place where it was set:

```
find . -name CMakeLists.txt | xargs grep msse2
```

You will find something like:

```
# Switch -msse2 enables vectorization. Remove if your CPU/compiler doesn't support it.
SET(OV_EIGEN_FLAGS "-msse2")
```

As guided, remove *every* occurrence, and you are done.

Comment: thank you so much. i removed those `SET(OV_EIGEN_FLAGS "-msse2")` and it did the magic!

Comment: hey @ivaigult , i was building and it was almost half through [147/360] and it just ran into a fatal error and wont proceed from here! 
`fatal error: Eigen/Eigen: No such file or directory` 
`#include <Eigen/Eigen>` 
`compilation terminated.` 
`ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.` 
`ERROR: Build failed` 
`Error while building sdk` 
how should i modify this `SET(OV_EIGEN_FLAGS "-msse2")` if i have to put it back in code again?

Comment: @ali2569 That's a different issue. You don't have _Eigen_ library installed. Use your package manager to install one.